# How to merge multiple feature vectors in DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-ml

Using Spark ML transformers I arrived at a `DataFrame` where each row looks like this:

```
Row(object_id, text_features_vector, color_features, type_features)
```

where `text_features` is a sparse vector of term weights, `color_features` is a small 20-element (one-hot-encoder) dense vector of colors, and `type_features` is also a one-hot-encoder dense vector of types.

What would a good approach be (using Spark's facilities) to merge these features in one single, large array, so that I measure things like the **cosine distance** between any two objects?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [VectorAssembler](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#vectorassembler):

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

val df: DataFrame = ???

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("text_features", "color_features", "type_features"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val transformed = assembler.transform(df)
```

For PySpark example see: [Encode and assemble multiple features in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32982425/1560062)