# How to train Logistic Regression with apache spark ML with two column of text as features?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to train a Logistic regression model with Apache Spark. My dataframe looks like this.

```
StructType schema = new StructType(new StructField[]{
    new StructField("label", DataTypes.DoubleType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("text_A", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    new StructField("text_B", DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
});

Dataset<Row> trainingDataFrame =spark.createDataFrame(trainingdata, schema);
```

I want to use both `text_A` and `text_B` as features to train the model, yet I don't want to just concatenate both of them. I want to make them separate category of features (So if the same word shows up in `text_A` and `text_B`, they are considered as different feature). In the current lr class, it is using `features` column as the default and only features to train the model. Is it possible to use two different column as the training features? Or how can I merge these two text features into a single `features` column for training?

Answer (score 0):

So I actually studied around online and found [How to merge multiple feature vectors in DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33273712/how-to-merge-multiple-feature-vectors-in-dataframe) which seems to be an accurate answer to my question.