# Attach metadata to vector column in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

**Context:**
I have a data frame with two columns: label, and features.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [label: int, features: vector]
```

Where *features* is a mllib.linalg.VectorUDT of numeric type built using VectorAssembler.

**Question:**
Is there a way to assign a schema to the features vector? I want to keep track of the name of each feature.

**Tried so far:**

```
val defaultAttr = NumericAttribute.defaultAttr
val attrs = Array("feat1", "feat2", "feat3").map(defaultAttr.withName)
val attrGroup = new AttributeGroup("userFeatures", attrs.asInstanceOf[Array[Attribute]])
```

---

```
scala> attrGroup.toMetadata 
res197: org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"numeric":[{"idx":0,"name":"f1"},{"idx":1,"name":"f2"},{"idx":2,"name":"f3"}]},"num_attrs":3}}
```

But was not sure how to apply this to an existing data frame.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There at lest two options:

1. On existing `DataFrame` you can use `as` method with `metadata` argument:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.ml.attribute._

   val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
     (1, Vectors.dense(1.0, 2.0, 3.0))
   ))
   val df = rdd.toDF("label", "features")

   df.withColumn("features", $"features".as("_", attrGroup.toMetadata))
   ```
2. When you create new `DataFrame` convert `AttributeGroup` `toStructField` and use it as a schema for a given column:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType}

   val schema = StructType(Array(
     StructField("label", IntegerType, false),
     attrGroup.toStructField()
   ))

   spark.createDataFrame(
     rdd.map(row => Row.fromSeq(row.productIterator.toSeq)),
     schema)
   ```

If vector column has been created using `VectorAssembler` column  metadata describing parent columns should be already attached.

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val raw = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0)
)).toDF("id", "feat1", "feat2", "feat3")

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(Array("feat1", "feat2", "feat3"))
  .setOutputCol("features")

val dfWithMeta = assembler.transform(raw).select($"id", $"features")
dfWithMeta.schema.fields(1).metadata

// org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata = {"ml_attr":{"attrs":{"numeric":[
//   {"idx":0,"name":"feat1"},{"idx":1,"name":"feat2"},
//   {"idx":2,"name":"feat3"}]},"num_attrs":3}
```

Vector fields are not directly accessible using dot syntax (like `$features.feat1`) but can used by specialized tools like `VectorSlicer`:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorSlicer

val slicer = new VectorSlicer()
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("featuresSubset")
  .setNames(Array("feat1", "feat3"))

slicer.transform(dfWithMeta).show
// +---+-------------+--------------+
// | id|     features|featuresSubset|
// +---+-------------+--------------+
// |  1|[1.0,2.0,3.0]|     [1.0,3.0]|
// +---+-------------+--------------+
```

For PySpark see [How can I declare a Column as a categorical feature in a DataFrame for use in ml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37473380/1560062)

Comment: Could the "feat1" column be extracted using the name instead of the index?

Comment: Kind of. You can use `VectorSlicer`.

Comment: @zero323 I have doubts concerning the second approach. Spark doesn't seems to like it. For some reason it's considering that it's converting the label StructField into a Tuple.

Comment: @eliasah The approach is correct, the function passed was wrong. Thanks.

Comment: @zero323 great answer. Very informative and helpful