# How can I declare a Column as a categorical feature in a DataFrame for use in ml

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How can I declare that a given Column in my `DataFrame` contains categorical information?

I have a Spark SQL `DataFrame` which I loaded from a database. Many of the columns in this `DataFrame` have categorical information, but they are encoded as Longs (for privacy).

I want to be able to tell spark-ml that even though this column is Numerical the information is actually Categorical. The indexes of categories may have a few holes, and it is acceptable. (Ex. a column may have the values [1, 0, 0 ,4])

I am aware that there exists the `StringIndexer` but I would prefer to avoid the hassle of encoding and decoding, specially because I have many columns that have this behavior.

I would be looking for something that looks like the following

```
train = load_from_database()
categorical_cols = ["CategoricalColOfLongs1",
                    "CategoricalColOfLongs2"]
numeric_cols = ["NumericColOfLongs1"]

## This is what I am looking for
## this step detects the min and max value of both columns
## and adds metadata to indicate this as a categorical column
## with (1 + max - min) categories
categorizer = ColumnCategorizer(columns = categorical_cols,
                                autoDetectMinMax = True)
##

vectorizer = VectorAssembler(inputCols = categorical_cols + 
                                         numeric_cols,
                             outputCol = "features")
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier()
pipeline = Pipeline(stages = [categorizer, vectorizer, classifier])
model = pipeline.fit(train)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I would prefer to avoid the hassle of encoding and decoding,

You cannot really avoid this completely. Required metadata for categorical variable is actually a mapping between value and index. Still, there is no need to do it manually or to [create a custom transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32331848/create-a-custom-transformer-in-pyspark-ml/32337101#32337101). Lets assume you have data frame like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(pd.DataFrame({
    "x1": np.random.random(1000),
    "x2": np.random.choice(3, 1000),
    "x4": np.random.choice(5, 1000)
}))
```

All you need is an assembler and indexer:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler, VectorIndexer
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[
    VectorAssembler(inputCols=df.columns, outputCol="features_raw"),
    VectorIndexer(
        inputCol="features_raw", outputCol="features", maxCategories=10)])

transformed = pipeline.fit(df).transform(df)
transformed.schema.fields[-1].metadata

## {'ml_attr': {'attrs': {'nominal': [{'idx': 1,
##      'name': 'x2',
##      'ord': False,
##      'vals': ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0']},
##     {'idx': 2,
##      'name': 'x4',
##      'ord': False,
##      'vals': ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']}],
##    'numeric': [{'idx': 0, 'name': 'x1'}]},
##   'num_attrs': 3}}
```

This example also shows what type information you provide to mark given element of the vector as categorical variable

```
{
    'idx': 2,  # Index (position in vector)
    'name': 'x4',  # name
    'ord': False,  # is ordinal?
    # Mapping between value and label
    'vals': ['0.0', '1.0', '2.0', '3.0', '4.0']  
}
```

So if you want to build this from scratch all you have to do is correct schema:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import VectorUDT

# Lets assume we have only a vector
raw = transformed.select("features_raw")

# Dictionary equivalent to transformed.schema.fields[-1].metadata shown abov
meta = ... 
schema = StructType([StructField("features", VectorUDT(), metadata=meta)])

sqlContext.createDataFrame(raw.rdd, schema)
```

But it is quite inefficient due to required serialization, deserialization.

Since **Spark 2.2** you can also use metadata argument:

```
df.withColumn("features", col("features").alias("features", metadata=meta))
```

See also [Attach metadata to vector column in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35305154/1560062)

Answer (score 0):

Hey zero323 I used the same technique to look at the metadata and I coded up this `Transformer`.

```
def _transform(self, data):
    maxValues = self.getOrDefault(self.maxValues)
    categoricalCols = self.getOrDefault(self.categoricalCols)

    new_schema = types.StructType(data.schema.fields)
    new_data = data
    for (col, maxVal) in zip(categoricalCols, maxValues):
        # I have not decided if I should make a new column or
        # overwrite the original column
        new_col_name = col + "_categorical"

        new_data = new_data.withColumn(new_col_name,
                                       data[col].astype(types.DoubleType()))

        # metadata for a categorical column                                                                                                                                 
        meta = {u'ml_attr' : {u'vals' : [unicode(i) for i in range(maxVal + 1)],
                              u'type' : u'nominal',
                              u'name' : new_col_name}}

        new_schema.add(new_col_name, types.DoubleType(), True, meta)

    return data.sql_ctx.createDataFrame(new_data.rdd, new_schema)
```