# adding metadata to calculated field in SqlTransformer in Pyspark ML

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

adding metadata to a new field in pyspark is easy by

```
df.withColumn("foo", col("foo").alias("", metadata={...}))
```

**BUT** i have a need to do this in SqlTransformer , **without** custom transformer , as part of the ML pipeline.
so after i do:

```
scalerTransformer = StandardScaler(inputCol='features',
                                   outputCol='scaledFeatures')
```

i want to replace back the scaledFeatures column name to features.
something like :

```
fieldTransformer = SQLTransformer(statement="select scaledFeatures AS features FROM __THIS__")
```

but with the metadata stored in feautres column
the reason i do that is lack of support with custom transformations and certain kinds of transformers in JPMML-sparkml library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I declare a Column as a categorical feature in a DataFrame for use in ml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37473380/how-can-i-declare-a-column-as-a-categorical-feature-in-a-dataframe-for-use-in-ml)

Comment: Also [How to change column metadata in pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44273080/10465355)

Comment: guys, this is not a duplicate, i know the solution of creating a new column with the metadata , as i wrote in the first code line in my question.
but the question is how to do that in SqlTransformer , so i can do that as a pipeline step , without doing a custom transformer with :
    df =df.withColumn
line.