# Understanding Representation of Vector Column in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Before I used VectorAssembler() to consolidate some OneHotEncoded categorical features... My data frame looked like so :

```
|  Numerical|  HotEncoded1|   HotEncoded2
|  14460.0|    (44,[5],[1.0])|     (3,[0],[1.0])|
|  14460.0|    (44,[9],[1.0])|     (3,[0],[1.0])|
|  15181.0|    (44,[1],[1.0])|     (3,[0],[1.0])|
```

The first column is a numerical column and the other two columns represent the transformed data set for OneHotEncoded categorical features. After applying VectorAssembler(), my output becomes:

```
[(48,[0,1,9],[14460.0,1.0,1.0])]
[(48,[0,3,25],[12827.0,1.0,1.0])]
[(48,[0,1,18],[12828.0,1.0,1.0])]
```

I am unsure of what these numbers mean and cannot make sense of this transformed data set. Some clarification on what this output means would be great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This output is not specific to `VectorAssembler`. It is just a string representation of `o.a.s.ml.linalg.SparseVector` (`o.a.s.mllib.linalg.SparseVector` in Spark < 2.0) with:

- leading number representing the length of a vector
- the first first set of numbers in brackets is a list of non-zero indices
- the second set of numbers in brackets is a list of values corresponding to the indices

So `(48,[0,1,9],[14460.0,1.0,1.0])` represents a vector of length 48, with three non-zero entries:

- 14460.0 at the 0th position
- 1.0 at the 1st position
- 1.0 at the 9th position

Pretty much the same description applies to `HotEncoded1` and `HotEncoded2` and `Numerical` is just a scalar. Without seeing [metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35305154/1560062) and constructors it is not possible to tell much but encoded variables should have either 44 and 3 or 45 and 4 levels (depending on a `dropLast` parameter).