# Spark CountVectorizer return udt instead of vector

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I try to create a vector of token counts for a LDA analysis in Spark 2.3.0. I have followed some tutorial and at each time they use CountVectorizer to easily convert Array of String to Vector.

I run this short example on my Databricks notebook :

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.CountVectorizer

val testW = Seq(
  (8, Array("Zara", "Nuha", "Ayan", "markle")),
  (9, Array("fdas", "test", "Ayan", "markle")),
  (10, Array("qwertzu", "test", "Ayan", "fdaf"))
  ).toDF("id", "filtered")

// Set params for CountVectorizer
val vectorizer = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("filtered")
  .setOutputCol("features")
  .setVocabSize(5) 
  .setMinDF(2) 
  .fit(testW)

// Create vector of token counts
val articlesCountVector = vectorizer.transform(testW).select("id", "features")
display(articlesCountVector)
```

and the output is the following :
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mq8vb.png)

But in all tutorial I have read, the type of "features" is **vector**.
Why in my case is it **udt** ?

Did i forget something ? Why it is not a vector ?

Is it possible to convert it ? because I cannot create LDA model with this udt type.

Comment: try `articlesCountVector.printSchema()` you should see vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue here. What is you see, is the detail of implementation of the Databricks display functions.

Internally, both `o.a.s.ml.linalg.Vector` and `o.a.s.mllib.linalg.Vector` are not natively represented in the `Dataset` API, and use `UDT`s (`UserDefinedTypes`). Hence the output.

You can find the exact meaning of all fields in [Understanding Output of VectorAssembler --- Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38236389)