# Spark CountVectorizer return a TinyInt

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I first ask my question on this page :
[Spark CountVectorizer return udt instead of vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50567836/spark-countvectorizer-return-udt-instead-of-vector?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The answer was quite correct. I have another question, if you clearly check my CountVectorizer output
the format is the following : [**0**, 3, ...]

After check inside my Databricks notebook it seems that the format of this line is the following :

```
features` AS STRUCT<`type`: TINYINT, `size`: INT, `indices`: ARRAY<INT>, `values`: ARRAY<DOUBLE>>
```

But after checking the JavaDoc of CountVectorizer, I see that "type" nowhere.

What is it and how to remove it ?
Because this leads me to a

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CAST(`features` AS STRUCT<`type`: TINYINT, `size`: INT, `indices`: ARRAY<INT>, `values`: ARRAY<DOUBLE>>)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast vector to vector;
```

when i try to convert him to RDD for my LDA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing two different things:

- Schema type and external type of the column -  in this case `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.SQLDataTypes.VectorType` and `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector` respectively.
- Internal representation of the `UserDefinedType` (its `sqlType`).

Internal attributes of the `UserDefinedType` [are in general not accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33747851/8371915).

You might be able to access internal structure, using `to_json` - `from_json` trick, similarly to what is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42591686/8371915),

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val schema = StructType(Seq(StructField(
  "features", 
  StructType(Seq(
    StructField("indices", ArrayType(LongType, true), true), 
    StructField("size", LongType, true),
    StructField("type", ShortType, true), 
    StructField("values", ArrayType(DoubleType, true), true)
)), true)))

df.select(
  from_json(
    to_json(struct($"features")), schema
   ).getItem("features").alias("data")
)
```

but considering that

> i try to convert him to RDD for my LDA.

it is just a waste of time. If you're using `Datasets` go with new `o.a.s.ml` API, which already provides LDA implementation. Please follow the examples in the official documentation for details - [Latent Dirichlet allocation (LDA)](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda)

Comment: Indeed, it is much easier with this API. I created a pipeline [link](https://databricks-prod-cloudfront.cloud.databricks.com/public/4027ec902e239c93eaaa8714f173bcfc/8599738367597028/1359427237536511/3601578643761083/latest.html) and everything works now thanks.