# Pyspark CSV to RDD to CoordinateMatrix

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to make the contents of a csv file to a `CoordinateMatrix`:

The dataset is here http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.tab.txt
which I converted to a csv file.

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import  RowMatrix, IndexedRowMatrix,CoordinateMatrix, MatrixEntry

entries = sc.parallelize([MatrixEntry(0, 0, 1.2),MatrixEntry(1, 0, 2), MatrixEntry(2, 1, 3.7)])

print type(entries)

mat = CoordinateMatrix(entries)

mat_transposed = mat.transpose()

mat_transposed = mat_transposed.toIndexedRowMatrix()
print(mat_transposed.numRows())


# # Load CSV File to a PySpark DataFrame
# 

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

#df= sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(header='true', inferschema='true').load('dataset.csv')
data = sc.textFile("dataset.csv")
#myrdd = sc.textFile("dataset.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))


 noHeaderRDD = data.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (row,index): index > 0).keys()
 #mat_data = CoordinateMatrix(noHeaderRDD)
```

I want to put the contents of my csv to a coordinate matrix but it seems im getting an error

Here is the error after attempting to make a coordinatematrix

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-718d73b097b2> in <module>()
----> 1 mat_data = CoordinateMatrix(noHeaderRDD)

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\mllib\linalg\distributed.pyc in __init__(self, entries, numRows, numCols)
    797             # each be easily serialized. We will convert back to
    798             # MatrixEntry inputs on the Scala side.
--> 799             java_matrix = callMLlibFunc("createCoordinateMatrix", entries.toDF(),
    800                                         long(numRows), long(numCols))
    801         elif (isinstance(entries, JavaObject)

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.pyc in toDF(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     55         [Row(name=u'Alice', age=1)]
     56         """
---> 57         return sparkSession.createDataFrame(self, schema, sampleRatio)
     58 
     59     RDD.toDF = toDF

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.pyc in createDataFrame(self, data, schema, samplingRatio, verifySchema)
    533 
    534         if isinstance(data, RDD):
--> 535             rdd, schema = self._createFromRDD(data.map(prepare), schema, samplingRatio)
    536         else:
    537             rdd, schema = self._createFromLocal(map(prepare, data), schema)

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.pyc in _createFromRDD(self, rdd, schema, samplingRatio)
    373         """
    374         if schema is None or isinstance(schema, (list, tuple)):
--> 375             struct = self._inferSchema(rdd, samplingRatio)
    376             converter = _create_converter(struct)
    377             rdd = rdd.map(converter)

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\session.pyc in _inferSchema(self, rdd, samplingRatio)
    344         :return: :class:`pyspark.sql.types.StructType`
    345         """
--> 346         first = rdd.first()
    347         if not first:
    348             raise ValueError("The first row in RDD is empty, "

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in first(self)
   1359         ValueError: RDD is empty
   1360         """
-> 1361         rs = self.take(1)
   1362         if rs:
   1363             return rs[0]

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.pyc in take(self, num)
   1341 
   1342             p = range(partsScanned, min(partsScanned + numPartsToTry, totalParts))
-> 1343             res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
   1344 
   1345             items += res

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\context.pyc in runJob(self, rdd, partitionFunc, partitions, allowLocal)
    990         # SparkContext#runJob.
    991         mappedRDD = rdd.mapPartitions(partitionFunc)
--> 992         port = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
    993         return list(_load_from_socket(port, mappedRDD._jrdd_deserializer))
    994 

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1131         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1132         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1133             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1134 
   1135         for temp_arg in temp_args:

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.pyc in deco(*a, **kw)
     61     def deco(*a, **kw):
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
     65             s = e.java_exception.toString()

D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    317                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    318                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 319                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    320             else:
    321                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 16.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 16.0 (TID 27, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\linalg\distributed.py", line 748, in _convert_to_matrix_entry
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into MatrixEntry" % type(entry))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'unicode'> into MatrixEntry

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1499)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1487)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1486)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:814)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1714)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1669)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1658)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:630)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2022)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2043)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2062)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:446)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 177, in main
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\worker.py", line 172, in process
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\serializers.py", line 268, in dump_stream
    vs = list(itertools.islice(iterator, batch))
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\rdd.py", line 1339, in takeUpToNumLeft
    yield next(iterator)
  File "D:\opt\spark\spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\mllib\linalg\distributed.py", line 748, in _convert_to_matrix_entry
    raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into MatrixEntry" % type(entry))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'unicode'> into MatrixEntry

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more
```

Any way to do this? seems that I need the content of my csv file to be a MatrixEntry object?

```
TypeError: Cannot convert type <type 'unicode'> into MatrixEntry
```

Comment: Can I recommend [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)?

Comment: Sorry. thank you  for the read

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR** Your code fails, because you pipe unparsed strings. You have parse data to a form, that can be converted to `MatrixEntry`.

If `dataset.csv` looks like:

```
i,j,v
1,2,3
2,1,0
```

you can just:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

mat = CoordinateMatrix(
    spark.read
        .option("header", "true")
        .schema("i long, j long, v double")
        .csv("dataset.csv")
        .rdd
)
```

Before 2.3 replace:

```
.schema("i long, j long, v double")
```

with

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

.schema(StructType([
    StructField("i", LongType()),
    StructField("j", LongType()),
    StructField("v", DoubleType())
]))
```

Comment: I tried your code. it gives me an error  raise TypeError("Cannot convert type %s into MatrixEntry" % type(entry))
TypeError: Cannot convert type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.Row'> into MatrixEntry  It had an error on the line .csv("dataset.csv")

Comment: The problem is that your data doesn't look like anything that can be converted to CoordinateMatrix.

Comment: Can you suggest anything? I want to use columnsimilarities on that dataset but I need to transpose it first

Comment: [Encode and assemble multiple features in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32982425/8371915) and then get vectors and convert to RDD. But if you wan to compare Rows and data is long it won't scale.

Comment: Even with a three-column data set, your approach does not work. It still has the problem thta you are passing a `sql.Row` into the constructor for `MatrixEntry`.