# Adding a Vectors Column to a pyspark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

How do I add a `Vectors.dense` column to a pyspark dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector

py_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"time": [59., 115., 156., 421.], "event": [1, 1, 1, 0]})

sc = SparkContext(master="local")
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(py_df)
sdf.withColumn("features", DenseVector(1))
```

Gives an error in file `anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py`, line 1848:

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

It doesn't like the `DenseVector` type as a column. Essentially, I have a pandas dataframe that I'd like to transform to a pyspark dataframe and add a column of the type `Vectors.dense`. Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Constant `Vectors` cannot be added as literal. You have to use `udf`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT

one = udf(lambda: DenseVector([1]), VectorUDT())
sdf.withColumn("features", one()).show()
```

But I am not sure why you need that at all. If you want to transform existing columns into `Vectors` use appropriate `pyspark.ml` tools, like `VectorAssembler` - [Encode and assemble multiple features in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32982425/9613318)

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler

VectorAssembler(inputCols=["time"], outputCol="features").transform(sdf)
```

Comment: Thanks! I want to call `AFTSurvivalRegression`, and it only works if the "features" columns are of the type `VectorUDT`.

Comment: Then use `pyspark.ml.features` utilities.