# Store DenseVector in DataFrame column in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to store a DenseVector into a DataFrame in a new column.

I tried the following code, but got an `AttributeError` saying `'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},
                            {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 2}])

vec = Vectors.dense([1.0, 3.0, 2.9])

df.withColumn('vector', functions.lit(vec))
```

I'm hoping to store a vector per row for computation purpose. Any help is appreciated.

[Python 3.7.3, Spark version 2.4.3, via Jupyter All-Spark-Notebook]

**EDIT**

I tried to follow the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832877/adding-a-vectors-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe) as suggested by Florian, but I could not adapt the udf to take in a custom pre-constructed vector.

```
conv = functions.udf(lambda x: DenseVector(x), VectorUDT())
# Same with
# conv = functions.udf(lambda x: x, VectorUDT())

df.withColumn('vector', conv(vec)).show()
```

I get this error :

```
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: [1.0,3.0,2.9] of type <class 'pyspark.mllib.linalg.DenseVector'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' or 'create_map' function.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a Vectors Column to a pyspark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49832877/adding-a-vectors-column-to-a-pyspark-dataframe). Does the answer there help you?

Comment: Thanks @Florian. Any idea how to modify the udf so that I can pass in my own vector? I followed the answer there and tried `udf(lambda x: x, VectorUDT())`, but it didn't work.

Comment: thi seems to work - `df.withColumn('vector', functions.array([functions.lit(k) for k in vec]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the creation of the `udf` inside a function, so it returns the `udf` with your vector. An example is given below, hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import VectorUDT, DenseVector

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},
                            {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 2}])

def vector_column(x): 
    return F.udf(lambda: x, VectorUDT())()

vec = DenseVector([1.0, 3.0, 2.9])
df.withColumn("vector", vector_column(vec)).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-----+-------------+
|age| name|       vector|
+---+-----+-------------+
|  1|Alice|[1.0,3.0,2.9]|
|  2|  Bob|[1.0,3.0,2.9]|
+---+-----+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Florian. Can confirm that this works. Could you explain why sometimes wrapping a udf inside a function is necessary? Or is this the recommended way to use a udf?

Comment: Well strictly speaking, you do not need to wrap the udf inside a function here, `df.withColumn("vector", F.udf(lambda: DenseVector([1.0, 3.0, 2.9]), VectorUDT())())` would also work. For reusability however, I find it cleaner to put this statement in a function that returns the UDF for us.

Answer (score 0):

Another way get the same effect without using `UDF`s is to wrap the `DenseVector` in a Dataframe and apply a cartesian product operation:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.ml.linalg import DenseVector

df = spark.createDataFrame([{'name': 'Alice', 'age': 1},
                            {'name': 'Bob', 'age': 2}])

df2 = spark.createDataFrame([{'vec' : DenseVector([1.0, 3.0, 2.9])}])
df.crossJoin(df2).show()
```

```
+---+-----+-------------+
|age| name|          vec|
+---+-----+-------------+
|  1|Alice|[1.0,3.0,2.9]|
|  2|  Bob|[1.0,3.0,2.9]|
+---+-----+-------------+
```